# BiPublisher Sheet name of .xpt report when outputting as excel

Tags: bi-publisher

Currently, when displaying (downloading) my .xpt bipublisher report as a .xlsx, my only sheet's name is Sheet1. I would like to rename it.

I know you can create xls templates directly and simply rename the sheet, but I'd need to recreate the whole report...

Answer (score 0):

For RTF templates, you can specify a `spreadsheet-sheet-name` command.

This is from the [Oracle Fusion Middleware Report Designer's Guide for Oracle Business Intelligence Publisher - 11g Release 1 (11.1.1)](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E28280_01/bi.1111/e22254/create_rtf_tmpl.htm#BIPRD2354) regarding RTF templates:

> `<?spreadsheet-sheet-name: xpath-expression?>`
>
> Where `xpath-expression` is an XPath expression or a string constant.

The example given is:

> `<?spreadsheet-sheet-name: {concat(.//YEAR, ' ',.//STATE)}?>`

(The guide for 12.2.1 has the same; I do know know about anything prior to 11.1.1.)

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer! To be honest, I dont know much about BiPublisher, this is one of my more low priority requests. I'm aware I can replicate my "report/state" ( It's called an "état" in french ) as an xls or rtf and build with the bipublisher plugin in either word or excel, which is what I started doing... The report in question was created inside BiPublisher. Whenever you create a new report, instead of uploading your RTF/XSL, if you click one of the base models that's what you'll get.

Answer (score 0):

Using a RTF you can actually created multi-sheet excel file and also you can rename the sheet. In order to create multiple sheet you need the following instruction:

```
<?split-by-page-break:?>
```

And before that instruction you need you use this one:

```
<?spreadsheet-sheet-name: xpath-expression?>
```

Next some examples:

```
<?spreadsheet-sheet-name: {concat(.//name, '')}?> --> It concatenates
<?spreadsheet-sheet-name: {.//name}?>   --> It only use the XML field
<?spreadsheet-sheet-name: {normalize-space(upper-case(.//name))}?> --> It applied a trim and upper functions
```

In my case in my XML data file, i have this field called "name" in a third level:

```
<sales>
 <division>
 <name>Groceries</name>
 <year>2014</year>
 <totalsales>3810</totalsales>
 <costofsales>2100</costofsales>
 </division>
 <division>
...
```